# Terminate Horizontal line on Price cross

Tags: pine-script

I am drawing a new line from a candle at a price(tprice). I wish to terminate this line the moment its crossed on the downside..ie it should stop continuing to right after it is touched  or a contrary sell signal is generated. The present code is below:

```
if(buySignal1 and barstate.isconfirmed) 
l1 := line.new(bar_index[1], tprice, bar_index, tprice, color=color.green, style=line.style_solid, width=2, extend=true ? extend.right : extend.both)
label label1 = label.new(bar_index, tprice, "TBuy", textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_none)
line.delete(l1[1])
label.delete(label1[1])
```

Can someone help me solve this please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get on your way. When you post code, post a compilable snippet including all dependencies; it makes it easier for others to help.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
bool buySignal1 = rising(close, 4)
bool sellSignal1 = falling(close, 4)
var float tprice = na
var line l1 = na
bool xLine = sign(close[1] - tprice) != sign(close - tprice)

if (buySignal1 and barstate.isconfirmed)
    tprice := low[1]
    label label1 = label.new(bar_index, tprice, "TBuy", textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_none)
    l1 := line.new(bar_index[1], tprice, bar_index, tprice, color=color.green, width=2)
else if not na(l1)
    if sellSignal1 or xLine
        tprice := na
        l1 := na
    else
        line.set_x2(l1, bar_index)
        line(na)

// Debugging
plotchar(buySignal1, "buySignal1", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(sellSignal1, "sellSignal1", "▼", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(xLine, "xLine", "—", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and get back in case of any doubts